# Problem with evaluating integers with LaTeX3 with an intermediate variable

Tags: expl3, programming, latex3, xparse

I have two codes for evaluating number. First of it for evaluating floating point number:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\evaluate}{m}
 { \fp_set:Nn \l_myvar_fp {#1}
   \fp_eval:n { \l_myvar_fp }

 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\evaluate{2+3}

\end{document}
```

> It is well done and I get correct answer.

Then of it for evaluating integer number:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\evaluate}{m}
 { \int_set:Nn \l_myvar_int {#1}
   \int_eval:n { \l_myvar_int }

 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\evaluate{2+3}

\end{document}
```

In the second example I just change `fp` to `int`, but I get an error in the second case:

> Undefined control sequence

But if I directly use `\int_eval:n` without using an intermediate variable `\l_myvar_int` it is well done.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\evaluate}{m}
 { \int_eval:n { #1 }

 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\evaluate{2+3}

\end{document}
```

Only after definition variable via `\int_new:N \l_myvar_int` it is successfully compiled.

Why in first case code well done without definition of a new variable, but it the second case does not?

Comment: Well, either it is a bug or a design flaw. `\int_set:Nn` does not define the variable, whereas `\fp_set:Nn` does

Comment: `\int_set:Nn` does not define, but `\fp_set:Nn` does. Well, this is not obvious and confusing.

Comment: BTW, not quite sure what you are up to here but you would normally either use `\<thing>_eval:n` directly or set a variable then `\<thing>_use:N` it.

Comment: @JosephWright Thanks, I know about using `\<thing>_eval:n` directly. But when I introduced an intermediate variable I got an error and ask here. Is the `\<thing>_use:N` a synonym of `\<thing>_eval:N` in my case?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer This is neither a bug nor a design flaw.  It is a consequence of the fact that fps are just macros whereas ints are count registers.  A count register has to be allocated before writing, macros can always be overwritten.  Adding a check for fps is unnecessary overhead.

Comment: @HenriMenke: Yes, macros may be overwritten, which means that they are defined before or newly defined in the `\fp_...` context, which does not lead to L3 complaining.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've not declared your variables. Due to the underlying implementation detail, *some* variable types may allow you to set them without declaration. However, this is not something that is supported (as in we reserve the right to change things). You can force `expl3` to check declarations, thus

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[check-declarations]{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\evaluate}{m}
 { \fp_set:Nn \l_myvar_fp {#1}
   \fp_eval:n { \l_myvar_fp }

 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\evaluate{2+3}

\end{document}
```

will yield

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! LaTeX error: "check/non-declared-variable"
! 
! The variable \l_myvar_fp has not been declared on line 14.
! 
! See the LaTeX3 documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................
```

Checking is not active as-standard largely for performance reasons: for data types implemented as macros, checking needs extra macro code.

For development work, using

```
\usepackage[check-declarations]{expl3}
```

during testing is recommended, though in 'production' code one would normally omit the option.